GNS 480 - OBS resolver calibration fails
Question about VOR/OBS use with a GPS...
I'm installing a GNS 480 in my Cessna 150. I'm retaining the Bendix King KI-209A CDI in the plane.
I've got the resolver plumbed back to the GPS, but when I set up the resolver in the GPS, it says "Calibration Failed." Interestingly, on that same screen, it shows the OBS heading from the CDI. (More on that below)
I've confirmed on that the SIN/COS signals are getting back to the GPS. I'm not swearing that they are within spec, but they look at least reasonable on the oscilloscope.
The Garmin manual states: "The OBS resolver should be compatible with a standard 6-wire OBS interface...Any electrical zero crossing will work because the GNS 480 will calibrate out any errors." The CDI appears to cross zero at 45 degrees, according to both the GPS and the Bendix King manual.
FWIW, the 209A uses a single wire for the ground wire for all three signals: exciter, SIN and COS. I've spliced that into three separate wires at the CDI end, with each pair in a shielded, twisted pair cable.
Of the many trials I made with the Resolver Calibration page, one time the "Current Resolver Value" changed as I turned the OBS in the CDI. I tried to recreate that behavior another dozen times, with no success. Every other time, it will show the a value that changed proportionally with a recent OBS setting...but does not change as a turn the OBS.
Also notable, I mapped out every 30 degrees setting, the GPS reads 0 at CDI 45 and changes linearly...except that it turns the opposite way.
If you've read this far, your probably nerdy enough to appreciate this video, showing most of what I've described here: 


Any suggestions?

There are a number of reasons why most avionics installers hate synchros/resolvers with a passion. They are one of the earliest of the common analog interfaces and pretty much every manufacturer did their own thing. Eventually ARINC got around to addressing the subject, but there was no real standardization due to the large number of existing installations. If you do get a copy of ARINC 407-1 Synchro Systems Manual, it give a good explanation of theory. But with the lack of standards, the summary basically reads: When it works, you got it right.
So to your problem: You have three 2-wire circuits; sin, cos, and ref/excitation. Any one of them may be inverted signal/ground. Try swapping the two wires. An inverted ref can cause the OBS to rotate the wrong direction. If N and S are correct, but E and W are reversed, the sin signal is inverted. Similarly, if E and W are correct, but N and S are reversed, the cos is inverted. It's also possible the sin and cos signals are 'mislabeled'. It's not too common with resolvers but it does happen regularly with x, y, z synchros. The best advice from my experience is work through the combinations until it works.
One thing, I'm not familiar with is the GNS480 auto calibration logic. My primary concern is making sure each new configuration restarts the cal from the beginning. It may be worth a call to Garmin tech support.
